# Convert a column to allow total in hours and minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to convert data on an Excel sheet from hours recorded in format 1.40 (being 1HOUR 40 minutes) to 01:40 so I can add up a column. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the number of minutes based on your input, use the following formula, 1.40 being in A1:

```
=INT(A1)*60+MOD(A1,1)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the values "in-place", select the cells and run this small macro:

```
Sub FixFormat()
    Dim r As Range, d As Date
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, ".")
        d = TimeSerial(ary(0), Left(ary(1), 2), 0)
        r.Clear
        r.NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm"
        r.Value = d
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to convert to a time value, e.g. 1.40 to 1:40 as required

`=TEXT(A1*100,"0\:00")+0`

Custom format result cell as [h]:mm